# rich:tabPanel 3.3 auto generate id's where it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I have a rich:tabPanel where every rich:tab has a sub view and the same tile:

```
<rich:tabPanel dir="rtl" headerAlignment="right" switchType="server" id="bbb"> 
  <rich:tab label="#{l.father}"
            action="#{ParentsInfoControl.switchTosecond}"
            reRender="Hidden">
      <f:subview id="firstTab">
          <t:aliasBeansScope>
            <t:aliasBean alias="#{formId}" value="fatherTab:" />
            <tiles:insert component="/WEB-INF/tiles/objects/entityUpdateTile.jsp"
                          flush="false" />
          </t:aliasBeansScope>
      </f:subview>
  </rich:tab>
  <rich:tab label="#{l.mother}"
            action="#{ParentsInfoControl.switchToFirst}"
            id="aaa" reRender="Hidden">
      <f:subview id="secondTab">
        <t:aliasBeansScope>
            <t:aliasBean alias="#{formId}" value="secondTab:" />
            <tiles:insert component="/WEB-INF/tiles/objects/entityUpdateTile.jsp"
                          flush="false" />
        </t:aliasBeansScope>
      </f:subview>
  </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

The problem is that inside my tile I have ids and rich auto-generate the following j_id01 to the second tab and so own..
can I go around it and force rich not to do it ?...

I use Javascript methods (lots of them ) with a naming convention and I hope that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the problem is a known richfaces bug